# What are normal structures that could be misinterpreted as lacunar strokes on T1 or T2 brain MRI?

Tags: brain, mri, stroke

Trying to detect lacunar strokes in brain MRI, in T1 they look like a small black hole, whereas in T2 bright-white; located within white matter region.

My question is, are there any structures that can be found in a healthy brain that could look like that, and therefore be confused with a small lesion? (e.g a blood vessel, benign calcifications)

Answer (score 2):

So far I have found Dilated Virchow-Robin (VR) Spaces (a.k.a dilated perivascular spaces) which are not necessarily malign and have pretty much the exact aspect on T1 and T2. Ref: https://pubs.rsna.org/doi/full/10.1148/rg.274065722